# How do I make an input() detect if the user input is something other than a string?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and I wanted to generate a simple user input that asks for your name. I got the prompt to work but when I added code that detects if the input is not a string, it doesn't let me input anything at all.

It was working up until I added the code that tells the user if they used an unsupported character.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
while True:
  name = input('What is your name? ')
  if name is str:
    print('Hi,%s. ' % name)
  if name != str:
    print('That is not a valid character!')
```

Comment: input is always returns string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supplies methods to check if a string contains on alphabets, alphanumeric or numeric.

`isalpha()` returns True for strings with only alphabets.

`isalnum()` returns True for strings with only alphabets and numbers and nothing else.

`isdigit()` returns True for strings with only numbers.

Also your if-else statement is off

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
if name.isalpha():
  print('Hi,%s. ' % name)
else:
  print('That is not a valid character!')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
```

you get a string called `name`, so checking it it is a string won't work.

What you can check is if it's an alphabetical character, using `isalpha`:

```
if name.isalpha():
    # as you were
```

There are various other string methods ( see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) ) which start `is` to check for numbers, lower case, spaces and so on.